# Safely running Fork bomb without using ulimit or bash FUNCNEST

Tags: bash

I have been researching about fork bomb and how it can be prevented.

I have found two ways to safely execute fork bomb code.

One of them is to set `ulimit` either temporary or permanently.

Another way is to set `FUNCNEST` in bash,

```
export FUNCNEST=2
```

I recently learned about `FUNCNEST` and wondering if there is any other way to safely execute fork bomb?

Answer (score 0):

You can run bash inside of a cgroup. All of its descendants will be restricted by the cgroup's resource limits.